# Check devices with Apple Pay capability

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, applepay

I want to know is there any API or piece of code to check weather a device is capable for Apple Pay.

I don't want to add static `if else` to check. 
As we know Apple Pay is supported with minimum iOS 8.3 and iPhone 5S and above.

I am showing informative images in my app and they should come only if device is capable of Apple Pay.
Means it should not come for iPhone 4/4S or all other devices with iOS less than 8.3

As per apple the following methods help me identifing if device supports payments. (Not exactly what I am looking for)

```
+ canMakePayments
+ canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:
+ canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:capabilities:
```

any help please.
thanks in advance.

Comment: If your deployment target is below iOS 8.3 you will also need to check if the `PKPayment` view controllers and methods are available before carrying out the check for Apple Pay support.

Comment: @RoboticCat thanks for the reply... yeah thats correct need to do that but how to check device itself has the capability for Apple Pay.

Comment: canMakePayments, canMakePaymentsUsingNetwork, canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:capabilities... these methods will return yes if we can make payment or wallet has the card added.

Answer (score 9):

As per the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController/canMakePayments) `+canMakePayments` is the call you want. It will return YES if the device supports it regardless of cards being configured.

> On devices that support making payments but don’t have any payment
>   cards configured, the canMakePayments method returns YES because the
>   hardware and parental controls allow making payments, but the
>   canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks: method returns NO regardless of network.

Answer (score 3):

You can check like this..

```
if([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:@[PKPaymentNetworkAmex, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkVisa]]) 
 {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this will check weather device can make payments and it has either of the card added in wallet.

Comment: Not specific for my solution need weather to know device has capability to support Apple Pay itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
let paymentNetworks = [PKPaymentNetworkAmex, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard,  PKPaymentNetworkVisa]
if   PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks(paymentNetworks) {
// Pay is available!
} else {

}
```